# Difficulty with Jensen's Equation.

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, functional-equations

Its easy to find all continuous function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ satisfing the Jensen equation 
$$f \left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right )=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$

But I am finding difficulty in finding all function  continuous on $(a,b),a,b \in \Bbb R$, satisfying the Jensen equation.

Comment: Some related posts: [How to show that $f$ is a straight line if $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646324) and [Function that is both midpoint convex and concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850101).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: First solve the question for functions defined on a closed interval, rather than open. Then think of an open interval as the (infinite) union of closed intervals.