# Function that is both midpoint convex and concave: $f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

> Which functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ do satisfy Jensen's functional equation
> $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
> for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

I think the only ones are of type $f(x) = c$ for some constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and the solutions of the Cauchy functional equation $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ and the sums and constant multiples of these functions. Are there other functions which are both midpoint convex and concave?

Comment: Here is a post about *continuous* solutions of Jensen's equation: [How to show that $f$ is a straight line if $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646324)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without loss, translate so that $f(0) = 0$. Then we have

$$f(x) = f\left(\frac{2x + 0}{2}\right) = \frac{f(2x)}{2}$$

so that $f(2x) = 2 f(x)$.

---

Now suppose that $f$ is midpoint convex and concave. We show it satisfies the Cauchy equation:

$$f(x + y) = f\left(\frac{2x + 2y}{2}\right) = \frac{f(2x) + f(2y)}{2} = f(x) + f(y)$$
as claimed. Now just remember that multiples of solutions to the Cauchy equation are still solutions to the Cauchy equation - hence, functions with your property are exactly translates of functions which solve the Cauchy equation.

Comment: "functions with your property are exactly functions which solve the Cauchy equation" - That is false: $f(x) = 1$ is a solution to the equation above but not a solution of Cauchy equation. Have I missed something?

Comment: @AndreiKh Yes, you're quite right. That's a translate of the zero function which *does* solve the Cauchy equation.

Comment: Ah - I didn't see "translates of functions". Thanks!

Comment: @AndreiKh Actually, what I had written was wrong until your correction - thanks.

Comment: @Andrei, do you mean continuous solutions? I suppose then, that we are looking at functions that  are traditionally called aff-ine (convex and concave) $F(\sigma x+ (1-\sigma) y)=\sigma F( x)+ (1-\sigma) F( y)$ where$ \sigma, (1-\sigma) \in [0,1]$ , note the last  weakening, where one cannot resolve $F(0)=0$ where otherwise this restriction is not kept when linear or cauchy and continuous. Generally of the form, $F(x)=Ax+B$, where if $F(0)=0$ and $F:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is cauchy. I am not sure if there counter-examples when not defined on the unit interval.

Comment: As 'affinity' given this restriction, even with $F(0)=0$, seems less expressive due to the restriction(by affinity i mean continuous convex and concave) with the $sigma$ terms having to sum to one

Comment: Nice answer. I will add for other users that more on Cauchy functional equation can be found in this post: [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, that's a nice FAQ I wasn't aware of.