# For $f(x)=4x^3+3x^2-x-1$, The Range of values $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$ can take is-

Tags: calculus

My Attempt :-

$f'(x)=12x^2+6x-1$ where $f'(x) \ge \frac{-7}{4}$. So (I think) from LMVT we can directly say that 
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ge \frac{-7}{4}$$  But the answer Given is $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > \frac{-7}{4}$$

So my Question is Is This Application of LMVT correct ,if yes then why $\frac{-7}{4}$ is excluded from the given range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, as long as $f'(x)$ attains its minimum at one single point, there won't exist two *distinct* points where the secant matches that slope.

To formalize, assume $f'(x)$ has a global minimum $m$, then it follows from MVT that:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ge m \quad \text{for} \;\;\forall a \ne b$$

If $a,b$ points exist where the *equality* holds, then by MVT for the intervals $(a,\frac{a+b}{2})$ and $(\frac{a+b}{2},b)$:

$$m = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2})}{\frac{b-a}{2}} + 
\frac{f(\frac{a+b}{2})-f(a)}{\frac{b-a}{2}}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2}(m+m) = m
$$

It follows that the middle inequality must be an equality as well, so:

$$m = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2})}{\frac{b-a}{2}} =  \frac{f(\frac{a+b}{2}) - f(a)}{\frac{b-a}{2}}
$$

From which:

$$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}$$

It follows that $f(x)$ is both midpoint convex and concave, thus linear by continuity (see for example [Function that is both midpoint convex and concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850101/function-that-is-both-midpoint-convex-and-concave/1850115)). But the given $f(x)$ is a $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial which is obviously not linear, so such points $a,b$ do not exist. Therefore the strict inequality holds.

Comment: I understood your answer up to  part on how $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2})}{\frac{b-a}{2}} +  \frac{f(\frac{a+b}{2})-f(a)}{\frac{b-a}{2}}\right) \ge m$$ But how did you conclude that the equality $$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(b)-f(\frac{a+b}{2})}{\frac{b-a}{2}} + 
\frac{f(\frac{a+b}{2})-f(a)}{\frac{b-a}{2}}\right) = m$$ will be satisfied ?

Comment: If you look at the two far ends of that it comes down to $m \ge m$ but of course $m=m$ so the inequality in between must be an equality.

Comment: Oh!!..How silly of me to miss that ....Also Does this also prove that for any given polynomial function $f(x)$(degree $\ge 3$) we will never be able to find  points such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ where $c$ is a point of maxima or minima of $f'(x)$ ?

Comment: That's the case for degree $3$ since $f'(x)$ has exactly one extremum. Not necessarily so for higher degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value theorem does not tell you that every $c$ has a corresponding $a$ and $b$ with $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c)$.  It tells you that given $a$ and $b$ you can find a $c$, but it doesn't say given $c$ you can find $a$ and $b$.  In your case,

$\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=4(a^2+ab+b^2)+3(a+b)-1=\dfrac{4(2a+2b+1)^2+(4a+1)^2+(4b+1)^2}{8}-\dfrac{7}{4}$.

The minimum of this thus occurs only for $a=b=-\frac{1}{4}$, but this is not allowed because then $a-b$ is $0$ in the denominator.  So there is no such $a$ and $b$ that gives you $-\frac{7}{4}$.